# REST Order By on multiple items not working

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I have REST Query for my OrderDetails List ,And I am unable to sort the rest api based on multiple items .

Can any one please guide me in knowing what's wrong in my below line of code.

```
http://mysite/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('OrderDetails')/items?Select=Title&$orderby=Order0,Sub_x0020_Order asc
```

Comment: Missing $ before select param

Comment: Also use eq instead of =

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a $ on select, that could be the issue

`http://mysite/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('OrderDetails')/items?$select=Title&$orderby=Order0,Sub_x0020_Order asc`

Comment: And the `select` must be in lowercase.

Comment: REST URL is case insensitive. Even this will work: "/_api/web/lists/getBYTITLe('OrderDetails')/items?$SeLecT=TiTlE"